# Wie übersetzt man "interventions"?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, mathematics

Der Kontext ist eine Akademie über Kausalität (Mathematik). Hier ein Auszug aus https://stat.ethz.ch/people/jopeters/index/edit/causalityHomepage/causality_files/scriptChapter1-4.pdf:

> Causal questions also appear in biological data sets, where
>   we try to predict the effect of interventions (e.g. gene knock-outs). Kemmeren et al.
>   [2014] measures genome-wide mRNA expression levels in yeast, we therefore have data
>   for p = 6170 genes. There are nobs = 160 “observational” samples of wild-types and
>   nint = 1479 data points for the “interventional” setting where each of them corresponds
>   to a strain for which a single gene k ∈ K := {k1, . . . , k1479} ⊂ {1, . . . , 6170} has
>   been deleted.

Was heißt "interventions" in diesem Kontext auf deutsch?

edit: Später, in der selben PDF:

> We use the SEM (structured equation model) to define not only the distribution of observed data but also so-called
>   interventional distributions (see Remark 2.2.5, for example). These are formally defined in
>   Definition 2.2.1.

und dann

> We are now ready to use the structure of SEMs to construct the “other distributions” P˜X
>   from P
>   X.
>   Definition 2.2.1 [Intervention Distribution] Consider a distribution P
>   X that has been generated
>   from an SEM S := (S, P
>   N). We can then replace one (or more) structural
>   equations (without generating cycles in the graph) and obtain a new SEM S˜. We call
>   the distributions in the new SEM intervention distributions and say that the variables
>   whose structural equation we have replaced have been “intervened on”. We denote the
>   new distribution by
>   P
>   X
>   S˜ = P
>   X | do(Xj=f˜( PA˜
>   j
>   ,N˜
>   j ))
>   S
>   .
>   The set of noise variables in S now contains both some “new” N˜’s and some “old” N’s
>   and is required to be mutually independent.
>   When ˜f( PA˜j, N˜j ) puts a point mass on a real value a, we simply write
>   P X | do(Xj=a) S
>   and call this a perfect intervention. An intervention with PA˜
>   j = PAj
>   is called imperfect. It’s a special case of a stochastic intervention [Korb et al., 2004], in which the marginal distribution of the intervened variable has positive variance.

Comment: Da fehlt halt einfach, was bedeuted "intervention" im Englischen hier? Wenn es nicht der Standardbegriff im Wörterbuch ist, eben mehr Kontext oder eine englische Begriffsdefinition.

Comment: Bitte, das Anführen von weiteren Formeln hilft nicht, das ist keine Kontext. Es sollte doch eine englische Begriffsdefinition geben, damit kann man dann arbeiten.

Comment: @Karl Das zweite ist die Definition.

Comment: Äh, ich bin selber Mathematiker, aber ich meinte eine nichtmathematische Definition, außerdem kann man einen Teil der Formeln sowieso nicht lesen. Es hat ja was mit Biologie zu tun, was ist die biologische Definition hier? Mit Formeln kommst Du hier nicht weiter IMHO.

Comment: Standardfrage: Was sagen denn die Wörterbücher? Wieso ist deren Antwort unbefriedigend?

Comment: Das steht (im mathematischen Kontext) nicht im Wörterbuch.

Comment: Hast Du den Text verstanden? Falls nicht, ist die Frage hier off-topic.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz Ich hatte gehofft durch die Sprache den Text besser zu verstehen. Warum soll das off-topic sein? Ich frage ja nicht nach einer Erklärung der Mathematik dahinter. Ich frage nach der üblichen Übsersetzung für "interventions" im mathematischen Kontext.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vom Sinn des Textes her erscheint *Eingriff* eine sinnvolle Übersetzung. Ob die aber bei den Statistikern so verwendet wird, ist eine andere Frage. Ich würde drei Dinge versuchen:

1. In der Statistikliteratur blätten.
2. In zbMATH mit *intervention* suchen, und dann auf Deutschspachiges einschränken.
3. Den Autor fragen. Der sollte ja an der ETH leicht per e-mail erreichbar sein.

Comment: Danke für den Hinweis auf zbMath :-) Es scheint kein häufiger Begriff zu sein, aber "Intervention" scheint auch im deutschen verwendet zu werden.

Comment: @moose Gerne geschehen!

Answer (score 3):

Mathematik schert sich in der Regel wenig darum, was man für einen Begriff benutzt, solange er genau definiert ist. Also ist die Frage "was heißt *interventions* in diesem Zusammenhang auf Deutsch" unpräzise. Mögliche Präzisierungen:

*Welche Übersetzung sollte man verwenden*? Da dar Begriff vermutlich neu ist, kann man es erstmal übersetzen, wie man möchte. Ob nun "interventionell", "interventionierend", "eingreifend", "durch einen Eingriff entstanden", oder wie auch immer. Im Laufe der Zeit wird sich die deutsche Literatur dann auf einen Begriff einigen. Oft, aber nicht immer, ist das eine wörtliche Entsprechung wie "interventionell". Es ist auch nicht unüblich, dass man sie nach einiger Zeit nach dem Erfinder benennt. Mögliche Übersetzungen findet man, indem man die entsprechende deutsche Literatur liest.

*Wo kommt dieser Begriff her, und wie ist er gemeint?* Das ist ja in dem zitierten Abschnitt erklärt: Es ist keine unabhängige Verteilung, sondern durch einen gezielten Eingriff ("intervention") entsteht eine Abhängigkeit. Diese Abhängigkeit ist aber nicht beliebig, und man möchte eine Klasse dieser durch gezielte Eingriffe bestimmter Art entstandenen abhängigen Verteilungen genauer untersuchen.

Comment: +1 für „Eingriff“.

Answer (score 1):

(Zugegeben ich kenne das Thema gar nicht) Ich würde den lateinischen Begriff verwenden: Was haltet ihr von *Interventionsverteilung* for *intervention distribution*?

<sub>feel specially free to downvote, I don't know this topic.</sub>

Comment: Nö, das ist eine gute Vermutung, aber ohne Zusammenhang hängt sie zusammenhanglos in der Luft.